MS Access LEFT JOIN query empty when referencing form in joined subquery
I'm building a project management database where the table [task_list] contains each kind of task that can be performed. The table [task_list] has a column self-reference column [parent_task].
The table [assignments] contains instantiations of tasks with fields like [project_ID], [employee_id], etc.
I'm attempting to create a query that for a given assignment returns all of the children for the task referenced in the [task_id] column as well as all of the instances of those children in the [assignments] table.
To do this, I created this LEFT JOIN query:
SELECT a.*, b.ID AS assignment_ID FROM 
    (
     SELECT task_list.* 
     FROM task_list 
     WHERE task_list.parent_task = [Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![task_id]
    ) AS a 
      LEFT JOIN 
    (
     SELECT * 
     FROM assignments 
     WHERE assignments.ID = [Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![id]
    ) AS b 
      ON a.ID = b.task_ID;

It returns no rows:

However, when I run the left side subquery on its own:
SELECT task_list.* 
FROM task_list 
WHERE task_list.parent_task = [Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![task_id];

It returns 2 rows:

That shouldn't happen. Because it's a LEFT JOIN, it shouldn't matter what's in the right side subquery. But I decided to run the right subquery as a sanity check and got one row:
SELECT * 
FROM assignments 
WHERE assignments.ID = [Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![id];


While trying to debug it, I discovered that if I enter the assignment ID instead of referencing the form in the query:
SELECT a.*, b.ID AS assignment_ID 
FROM (
      SELECT task_list.* 
      FROM task_list 
      WHERE task_list.parent_task = [Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![task_id]
     ) AS a 
       LEFT JOIN 
     (
      SELECT * 
      FROM assignments 
      WHERE assignments.ID = 2
     ) AS b 
       ON a.ID = b.task_ID;

It works as anticipated:

However, if I manually enter the ID in the left side subquery and keep the form reference in the right subquery, it still produces no rows:
SELECT a.*, b.ID AS assignment_ID 
FROM (
      SELECT task_list.* 
      FROM task_list 
      WHERE task_list.parent_task = 1
     ) AS a 
       LEFT JOIN 
     (
      SELECT * 
      FROM assignments 
      WHERE assignments.ID = 2
     ) AS b 
       ON a.ID = b.task_ID;

This would seem to suggest that there's something wrong with the form reference [Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![id] except that:

Both subqueries work as expected on their own.
It should still produce at least 2 rows of data regardless of what's in the right subquery since it's a LEFT join and the left side produces 2 rows on its own.

Also, I ran the following in the VBA editor:
Private Sub testthis()
    Debug.Print ([Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![task_id])
    Debug.Print ([Forms]![AssignmentsEdit]![id])
End Sub

And it produced the following output:
 1 
 2 

So it looks like the form references are indeed correct.
I'm absolutely stumped.
For what it's worth, the backend is in MS SQL Server.
If anyone can see anything wrong with my queries or knows of any bugs in MS Access, let me know!
UPDATED May 1, 10:49
Here are the contents of the tables in the queries. I've removed irrelevant columns and changed names for security reasons.
task_list:



ID
category_ID
task_name
parent_task




1
1
Make a PB and Jelly Sandwich



2
1
Check car oil level



3
2
Make bed



4
2
Run in a circle



5
2
Pet a cat



6
2
Make a cocktail



7
2
Visit a museum



8
2
See a movie



9
2
Play the cello



10
2
Open an umbrella



11
1
Go swimming



12
1
Tidy up the lawn



13
1
Wash a car



14
5
Use a fire extinguisher



15
4
Do the hokey-pokey



16
3
Take a walk



17
1
Apply PB to bread
1


18
1
Apply Jelly to Bread
1


19
1
Open hood
2


20
2
Add ingredients
6


21
2
Shake
6


22
2
Buy tickets
8


23
2
Buy popcorn
8


24
2
Read a book
9


25
2
Step outside first
10


26
1
Mow the grass
12


27
1
Use weed whacker
12


28
1
Scrub with soap
13


29
1
Rinse
13


30
1
Wax
13


31
5
Point at base of the fire
14


32
5
Squeeze trigger
14


33
4
Put right arm in
15


34
4
Put right leg in
15


35
4
Put left leg in
15


36
4
Take left leg out
15


37
3
Put whole self in
15


38
3
Take whole self out
15


39
3
Shake it all about
15



assignments:



ID
staff_ID
project_ID
task_ID
completed_on
parent_ID
prereq_ID




2
7
4
1







Provide sample data as formatted text table(s). You show task_list ID's of 17 and 18 then join to assignments task_ID of 1?

@Charlieface What you're seeing in the post is my full code. For each query, I copied and pasted the code directly into the post, ran the query, took a screenshot of the output, and then inserted the screenshot directly below the code.
The only editing was that done by June7 to increase readability (thanks for that, BTW!).

@June7 I've added sample data per your request.
I'm joining on task_list.parent_task, not task_list.ID, which is why a task_ID = 1 in the WHERE clause of the left subquery returns tasks with ID's 17 and 18 instead of 1.

I don't see a JOIN using parent_task - your SQL shows: ON a.ID = b.task_ID.

@June7 Good catch! I updated it to a.ID = b.parent_ID but still got nothing.

I built tables and form with your object naming. Where are you using query? What is purpose of form - data entry or select search criteria? Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide a representative database with your code.

Should that JOIN be a.parent_task = b.task_ID? You don't show data in assignments.parent_ID.
